# Parsekit: how to match individual quote characters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parsekit

When using the parser Parsekit for the iPhone. Is it possible to include against a double quote? And things which are part of the special BNF?
(Is it possible to escape sequences in a defined grammer?)

```
@start = doublequote+;
doublequote= '"'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer of ParseKit here.

By default you can match against quoted strings easily using the built-in `QuotedString` parser (which will match `QuotedString` tokens):

```
@start = quotes;
quotes = QuotedString+;
```

that would match input like: `"foo" 'bar' "baz"`

as three quoted strings: `"foo"`, `'bar'`, `"baz"`

So this demonstrates that by default the ParseKit tokenizer (the `PKTokenizer` class) produces `QuotedString` tokens when encountering a `"` or `'`.

For more details on default tokenizer behavior, read the [ParseKit tokenization documentation](http://parsekit.com/tokenization.html).

---

However, if you want quote chars (`"`, `'`) to be recognized as standalone **symbols** rather than indicating the start or end of a **quoted string**, you must alter the tokenizer behavior first.

In code, you would alter tokenizer behavior by calling methods on your `PKTokenizer` object.

In grammars, you alter tokenizer behavior with **tokenizer directives**.

**Tokenizer directives** are special rules placed at the top of your grammar which start with a `@` character. In this case, you want to change which characters are recognized as standalone **symbol tokens** by the tokenizer. Specifically, you want to **add** two chars as symbols with the `@symbolState` tokenizer directive.

You can do that in your grammar by changing it to:

```
@symbolState = '"' "'"; // a tokenizer directive stating ' and " should be recognized as standalone symbol tokens
                        // (by default they are start- and end-markers for quoted string tokens)

@start = stuff;
stuff = (Word | Symbol)+;
```

Given the same input as above, you would match separate quote symbols and words: `"`, `foo`, `"`, `'`, `bar`, `'`, `"`, `baz`, `"`